# First homology group of a closed, oriented, connected 3-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

I know that not every finitely presented group can appear as a fundamental group of a closed, oriented, connected $3$-manifold. On the other hand, can every finitely generated abelian group be realized as a first homology group over $\mathbb Z$ of a closed, oriented, connected $3$-manifold?

Comment: Lens spaces will give you any Z/n and S^1 x S^2 will give you Z. Then take connected sums.

Comment: @Johnny Evans So, in other words you are saying that every finitely generated abelian group is realizable this way. Right?

Comment: Yes (the connect sum gives you products, and all finitely generated abelian groups are products of these).